# windows phone push notifications 406 not acceptable

Tags: windows-phone, push-notification, mpns, http-status-code-406

I'm getting 406 Not Acceptable as response when I try to send a push notification, I understand the problem and I've fixed the code that was causing it but I'm not quite sure how to make the error go away, the server responds with 406 to every one of my requests for push notifications. Will this happen by itself after a period of time or? Thanks.

Comment: Fixed itself after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed itself after a while, half a day or so.

Comment: sorry, haven't logged in for a while, but for anyone else who cares - it sorts itself out after some time.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error you should (or could) do something about. It just means that you sent too many notifications to the same device or too many notifications per second, and you have to wait until you can send more.

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> This error occurs when an unauthenticated cloud service has reached the per-day throttling limit for a subscription, or when a cloud service (authenticated or unauthenticated) has sent too many notifications per second. The cloud service can try to re-send the push notification every hour after receiving this error. The cloud service may need to wait up to 24 hours before normal notification flow will resume.

([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941100%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))